# Makefile pattern rule fails?

Tags: gnu-make

While using GNU-make, my Makefile has some pattern rule as:

```
%.o:%.c
    gcc $< -o:$@
```

This rule is added by me.

But when I do make it gives an error saying No rule to make target %.o and doesn't build the targets.

At times, there is this other behaviour as well. It does not build the target when I say make first time(It gives error saying No rule to make target), but when i say make again immediately, it does build correctly.

So when i explicity specify each source file separately, then it builds the targets fine first time itself.

**EDIT: I am using GNU-make on a Centos (v6.3 i guess, not sure). Could this be some permission/user id /group id issue?**

Any pointers to understand what might be happening and solution for this?

thank you,
-AD.

Comment: Having the exact same problem here. God, I __hate__ makefiles and their stupid syntax and arbitrary limitations.

Answer (score 18):

Make only uses a pattern rule as a sort of fallback. For example:

```
$ ls
Makefile
$ cat Makefile
%.o: %.c
    gcc $< -o $@
$ make
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

This is fine. Make does not consider the pattern rule as you have not asked it to make anything, and there is no default target in the makefile. Let's ask it to make something that might use the pattern rule.

```
$ make 1.o
make: *** No rule to make target `1.o'.  Stop.
```

Expected. `1.c` does not exist, so the pattern rule is not considered. Let's try again.

```
$ touch 1.c
$ make 1.o
gcc 1.c -o 1.o
```

(and then some error about main being missing).

Personally I dislike these fallback rules intensely. I much prefer listing the targets explicitly. Something like

```
file.o file2.o f.o: %.o: %.c
    ...
```

gives you a Target Specific Pattern Rule. These are quite different (see the manual for [Static Pattern Rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html)). [Oh, and the pattern gives you no advantage in this noddy example.]

Comment: In the second example (similar to what I ran into), it seems a bit user-unfriendly that it says "No rule to make target `1.o'." rather than pointing out the rule(s) that failed to match because the file was missing. Arguably there *does* exist a rule; it's just that the preconditions are not satisfied.

Comment: It's an impossible job in general for _make_ to work out what files are missing. Remember that pattern rules can be chained together (`.yy`  → `.c` → `.o` etc.). `make -R` _is_ your friend.

Getting your prerequisites right is essential when writing makefiles. If they are wrong parallel make won't work, and you might as well use a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

If you put only this in a Makefile and call **make**:

```
%.o: %.cpp
  g++ -g -o $@ -c $<
```

It tells: `make: *** No targets.  Stop.`

Because it's not a target. It's a rule.

It will work if your another target needs a **.o** file.

```
main.exe: main.o add.o
  g++ -g -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
  g++ -g -o $@ -c $<
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need spaces around the `:` in the first line of your rule.  Also, `gcc` does not take a colon before the output file name; just use `-o $@`.

Comment: @Ok those are my typos. Makefile doesn't have any errors. Still the problem persists..

Comment: Can you try `make -d` on your target?  It spews a lot of output, but you can see what rules it is trying and maybe see what's going wrong.  You can also post the result if you think it would help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran through this problem.

If this is your rule:

```
%.o:%.c
    gcc $< -o:$@
```

Make sure that you have a tab and not spaces on the second line before the gcc. Took me a couple of hours to figure out.
Also no ':' after the -o flag, as somebody else pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the .c file exists?  I think using -d as suggested earlier should help debug this.