# Makefile pattern rules not working

Tags: makefile, erlang

I am learning makefiles, and can't just wrap my head around this problem i am having, and would like to understand how/why this fail.

I have half a dozen erlang files in a `src` directory. I want to compile these into a `ebin` directory, without having to define a rule for each and every one of them. According to the Gnu make documentation, [pattern rules should be right up my alley](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules).

However, with the following makefile, all I get from make is `make: *** No targets.  Stop`. Why is that?

```
 ebin/%.beam: src/%.erl
     mkdir -p ebin
     erlc -o ebin $<
```

Edit: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5194141/6616324), I now understand that i would have to explicitly declare the targets, for instance by using `make ebin/cmplx.beam`. However, i still do not understand how i should write my makefile to get my desired behaviour - since I have half a dozen targets (and in other projects even more), this seems like an unnecessary hassle. Is there not a way to define targets based on the source file names?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Makefile pattern rule fails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155510/makefile-pattern-rule-fails)

Comment: Makefiles are an old and too low-level (meaning: too easy to make human errors) way to build software. For Erlang, if you really want to stick to Makefiles, then I suggest the very good https://erlang.mk. If you want to consider other options, then https://www.rebar3.org. Outside Erlang, consider https://cmake.org/, that will generate either Makefiles or (better!) ninja configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target rule tells make that whenever it needs to produce a `beam` file in the `ebin` directory, and there exists a corresponding `erl` file in the `src` directory, it can use `erlc`.

However, this doesn't tell make that this is what it needs to do.  You could explicitly tell make what it needs to do by giving it a target on the command line:

```
make ebin/foo.beam
```

If you don't give a target on the command line, make will pick the first non-pattern rule in the makefile as its target.  However, your makefile doesn't have any non-pattern rules, so there is no target.

What you probably want is that for each existing `erl` file in `src`, make should consider the corresponding `beam` file in `ebin` to be a target. You can achieve that by calling `wildcard` and `patsubst`:

```
erl_files=$(wildcard src/*.erl)
beam_files=$(patsubst src/%.erl,ebin/%.beam,$(erl_files))

ebin/%.beam: src/%.erl
        mkdir -p ebin
        erlc -o ebin $<

all: $(beam_files)
```

(The indented lines need to be actual physical tabs, not spaces.)

That way, running `make` will rebuild all `beam` files that are out of date. `all` gets chosen as the default target, and it in turn depends on all `beam` existing or potential, each of which in turn depends on the corresponding `erl` file.

This trick is [described in the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html).