# Makefile to process a folder's contents

Tags: makefile

I have a folder with some markdown files I want to process using pandoc and output them into another folder for a Jekyll site. I am attempting to use the following Makefile:

```
MARKDOWN = $(wildcard *.md)

jekyll-build : _posts/$(MARKDOWN)
        bundle exec jekyll build

_posts/%.md : source/%.md
        pandoc -s -t markdown-citations -o $@ $<
```

However, instead of looking for the contents of the `_posts` folder, `make` is looking for any *.md files in the *current* working directory (where I have an index.md file), then complains it can't find `_posts/index.md`. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155510/makefile-pattern-rule-fails) I gather it's the expected behavior of pattern rules, so my question is: how do I get `make` to look for all existing files in the `source` folder and run the recipe on each one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MARKDOWN = $(wildcard source/*.md)

POSTS := $(patsubst source/%,_posts/%, $(MARKDOWN))

jekyll-build : $(POSTS)                                                                                  
    ...

_posts/%.md : source/%.md                                                                                
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you @Beta. Is it documented that concatenating the path and the variable---as I was doing with `path/to/$(VARIABLE)`---is not allowed?

Comment: It's definitely _allowed_.  It just doesn't do what you want.  You seem to be imagining that prepending a string to a variable will cause make to go through all the individual _words_ in that variable and prepend the string to each one... that's not what happens.  If your variable `FOO` has a value `foo bar biz`, then `pre/$(FOO)` expands to `pre/foo bar biz`.  It does _not_ expand to `pre/foo pre/bar pre/biz`.  Make works the same way pretty much every programming language that supports variable interpolation works: direct text substitution,